# "Media resource FILEPATH/FILENAME.mp4 could not be decoded." while trying to play h264 encoded files on Firefox 35

Tags: firefox, video-streaming, html5-video, h.264

We use mp4 files using the h264 codec on our server to play videos. The files in FF prior to FF35 worked fine, they work in IE8+, and Chrome. In FF35 we now get the following message in the console

```
Media resource FILEPATH/FILENAME.mp4 could not be decoded.
```

If we then load the resource directly we get

```
Video can't be played because the file is corrupt.
```

Is there something we have to do to the mp4 files to get them working in FF35? This behavior has been replicated on FF35 on OS 10.6.8-10.9, Windows 7, and Windows 8.

Comment: i have this problem since updating to firefox with all vine videos, but it works on clean profile, maybe report a bug to firefox?

Comment: Haven't had much luck with FF forums. Have you had any luck with getting the Vine to work for you?

Comment: Here's the firefox forum, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1041729

Comment: found what was causing the problem for me - user_pref("media.windows-media-foundation.enabled", false);

Comment: I had this issue on my mac (10.6.8) and setting the configuration option of 'media.fragmented-mp4.enabled' to 'false' made the site's videos play for me. So maybe the small set of videos you're serving are misencoded and firefox is stricter with their playing of mp4s?

Answer (score 0):

I tried few Firefox Addons to fix that, but non worked (in my case it happened with MOV files).

But here's what worked eventually:

1. Go to Firefox **`about:config`** (from address bar).
2. Search for **`mp4`**
3. It should list these entries:

> media.mediasource.mp4.enabled
>
> media.mp4.enabled

4. Double click each entry and change it to **`false`**
5. Restart Firefox and try to play the MP4/MOV file again.
6. Now it should prompt to choose Windows program to play it - choose your favorite player (mine is [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html)) and check it to be the default.

---

Some more troubleshooting about this issue:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1115863

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1019812

Comment: This isn't a programmatic answer. We'd have to tell hundreds/thousands of users to do this for our videos to be playable, and modifying clients browsers isn't something we should have to do.